# Truffle - Stub contract functions in Mocha

Tags: truffle, ether, mocha

How do I stub out contract functions while testing in truffle in javascript.

Normally in mocha I would import sinon and do a sinon.stub command.

It doesnt seem that I can import npm modules into the truffle testsuite.

I would like to test against the callcount and args of the transfer method in my contract.

Comment: importing sinon, sinon-chai, etc. isn't the problem.  There's no problem NPM packages, although you should use `require` rather than `import`.  One real issue you may have is that internal / private methods and attributes are not in the ABI, so you can't mock them.